# Eclipce RCP is crashed when starting

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, java-11

I work with the old legacy project and trying to switch it to Java 11.
At the moment I am able to compile it successfully, but it crashes when starting.

The project consists of several eclipse plugins modules and final eclipse-repository module which has product file (there is also pom file compiles all modules and creates executable file in target folder of the  eclipse-repository module)

Targed definition file is resolved succesfully too and looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?pde version="3.8"?>
<target name="phoenixldm-artifactory-p2" sequenceNumber="259">
  <locations>

    <location includeAllPlatforms="true" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
      <repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2019-09"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.birt.feature.group" version="4.7.0.v201706222054"/>
    </location>
        
    <location includeAllPlatforms="true" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
      <repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-12"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.sdk.feature.group" version="3.21.0.v20201128-0731"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.sdk.feature.group" version="4.18.0.v20201202-1800"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.jst.enterprise_ui.feature.feature.group" version="3.20.0.v202011230434"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.jst.web_ui.feature.feature.group" version="3.20.0.v202011230434"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.pde.feature.group" version="3.14.600.v20201202-1800"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.wst.web_ui.feature.feature.group" version="3.20.0.v202011230431"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group" version="3.20.0.v202011230430"/>
    </location>

 <location includeAllPlatforms="true" includeConfigurePhase="false" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
      <repository location="https://artifactory.in.XXX.com/artifactory/YYY/platform"/>
        <unit id="com.company.orm.platform.feature.feature.group" version="2.1.2"/>
        <unit id="com.company.orm.platform.feature.source.feature.group" version="2.1.2"/>
    </location>

    <location includeAllPlatforms="true" includeConfigurePhase="false" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
      <repository location="https://artifactory.in.XXX.com/artifactory/YYY/application"/>
        <unit id="com.company.orm.core.feature.feature.group" version="2.1.2"/>
        <unit id="com.company.orm.core.feature.source.feature.group" version="2.1.2"/>
        <unit id="com.company.update.feature.feature.group" version="2.1.2"/>
        <unit id="com.company.update.feature.source.feature.group" version="2.1.2"/>
    </location>
    
  </locations>
    
</target>
```

I'm using two version of eclipse: the latest 2020-12, and 2019-09 because this is the latest version with BIRT whose is used in our project.

My product file is feature-oriented, so the product  file looks like

```
<product name="Noname" uid="noname" version="1.1.1" useFeatures="true" includeLaunchers="true">

   <configIni use="default">
   </configIni>

   <launcherArgs>
      <programArgsLin>-os ${target.os} -ws ${target.ws} -arch ${target.arch} -consoleLog
      </programArgsLin>
      <programArgsWin>-os ${target.os} -ws ${target.ws} -arch ${target.arch} -consoleLog
      </programArgsWin>
      <vmArgsLin>-Xmx2048m -Xms512m -XX:+UseParallelGC -Xshare:auto -Declipse.ignoreApp=true -Dosgi.noShutdown=true -Dlogback.configurationFile=log.xml
      </vmArgsLin>
      <vmArgsMac>-XstartOnFirstThread -Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
      </vmArgsMac>
      <vmArgsWin>-Xmx768m -Xms256m -Xshare:auto -Declipse.ignoreApp=true -Dosgi.noShutdown=true -Dlogback.configurationFile=log.xml
      </vmArgsWin>
   </launcherArgs>

   <windowImages/>

   <launcher name="phoenix">
      <win useIco="false">
         <bmp/>
      </win>
   </launcher>

   <vm>
   </vm>

   <plugins>
   </plugins>

   <features>
      <feature id="com.company.comp.feature"/>
      <feature id="com.company.orm.core.feature"/>
      <feature id="com.company.orm.platform.feature"/>
      <feature id="org.eclipse.pde"/> <!-- added because can't find org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator -->
   </features>

     <configurations>
      <!-- all plug-ins from my features above -->
      <plugin id="org.apache.felix.scr" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.runtime" autoStart="true" startLevel="0" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.common" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.event" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator" autoStart="true" startLevel="1" />
   </configurations>

   <preferencesInfo>
      <targetfile overwrite="false"/>
   </preferencesInfo>

   <cssInfo>
   </cssInfo>

</product>
```

there is plugin in pom file

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>tycho-p2-director-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

which creates executable for the product.
If I start the executable I'll get "Segmetation fault"
When I start it as Run Configuration - Eclipse Application, then it will craches with log

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2021-01-30 12:46:42.659
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:650)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1461)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1434)
```

Unforunatelly, I am not sure that I do everything properly. May be someone could tell me where I'm wrong.

Comment: Is there more in the log than just that?

Comment: No. There are only these rows in the log

Comment: org.eclipse.pde is probably not the feature you want. org.eclipse.platform, or org.eclipse.sdk, or org.eclipse.rcp might be better. But debugging RCP builds from Stack Overflow questions is very hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that I found the root cause of my problem. At least my application can be running without crashing into a Segmentation fault. Unfortunately, it still complains about unresolved dependencies but it's a big step forward.
So, the problem was in
`<programArgsLin>-os ${target.os} -ws ${target.ws} -arch ${target.arch} -consoleLog`
in my product file.

removing **-os ${target.os} -ws ${target.ws} -arch ${target.arch}**
let the application run.

Thanks @greg-449, you're absolutely right about org.eclipse.pde - it is not a feature which I need.

I've refactored my product and it looks like

```
...
<launcherArgs>
      <programArgs>-consoleLog
      </programArgs>
      <vmArgs>-Xshare:auto -Declipse.ignoreApp=true -Dosgi.noShutdown=true -Dlogback.configurationFile=log.xml
      </vmArgs>
      <vmArgsLin>
         <argsX86_64>-Xmx2048m -Xms512m -XX:+UseParallelGC</argsX86_64>
      </vmArgsLin>
      <vmArgsMac>-XstartOnFirstThread -Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
      </vmArgsMac>
      <vmArgsWin>-Xmx768m -Xms256m
      </vmArgsWin>
   </launcherArgs>
...
<vm>
      <linux include="true">org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-11</linux>
      <macos include="true">org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-11</macos>
   </vm>
...
<features>
      ... list of my features ...
      <feature id="org.eclipse.e4.rcp" installMode="root"/>
      <feature id="org.eclipse.emf.ecore" installMode="root"/>
      <feature id="org.eclipse.emf.common" installMode="root"/>
</features>
<configurations>
      <plugin id="org.apache.felix.scr" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.runtime" autoStart="true" startLevel="0" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.common" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.event" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator" autoStart="true" startLevel="1" />
   </configurations>
```