# The right way to create Eclipse product

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, java-11

could someone from Eclipse guru explain in plain English what I do wrong? :) Suppose I have a multimodal maven project and each module is an eclipse plugin. Additionally, I have a module that creates an Eclipse feature(s) from these plugins.
I want to create an Eclipse product from all my features and run it as CLI application which is run by ant.
So, I create another module that contains a product file for my application.
I decided that my product will be feature-oriented, thus I add the  section in my product file and insert all my features there.

After that on "Configuration" tab I press "Add recommended" and Eclipse adds the next plugins

```
 <plugin id="org.apache.felix.scr" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
 <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.runtime" autoStart="true" startLevel="0" />
 <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.common" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
 <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.event" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
 <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator" autoStart="true" startLevel="1" />
```

in the configuration section of the product file.

I compile the whole of my maven project and receive an executable file that I can run in the terminal.

But unfortunately, when I start this file by command
`ant -propertyfile ant.cfg -f config/compile.xml`

I receive

```
BUILD FAILED
..... : exec returned: 139
```

When I start my executable file I receive "Segmentation fault"

So my question is: which plugins should I add to the configuration section of the product file?

P.S. There is a more detailed description in my another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65971888/eclipce-rcp-is-crashed-when-starting)
P.P.S There was a lot of additional plugins in the product file when this product was running by Java 8 on Eclipse Kepler, should I add all of them?

Comment: Unfortunately, when I press  'Add Required' nothing happens. Target platform is based on 2020-12. There is my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65971888/eclipce-rcp-is-crashed-when-starting) with configs.

Comment: Your product file is using 'features' which specify the plug-ins required, you can't add individual plug-ins to a feature based product.

Answer (score 0):

The root problem was not in the list of the features and plugins, but in
`<programArgsLin>-os ${target.os} -ws ${target.ws} -arch ${target.arch} -consoleLog`
After removing **-os ${target.os} -ws ${target.ws} -arch ${target.arch}** the application is starting without "Segmentation fault".

And about the list of the features and plugins - I've found the "an algorithm" :)

1. Open product file and on the "Contents" tab add all your features you need
2. Go to "Configuration" tab and press "Add Recomended", eclipse will add

```
<configurations>
      <plugin id="org.apache.felix.scr" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.runtime" autoStart="true" startLevel="0" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.common" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.event" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator" autoStart="true" startLevel="1" />
   </configurations>
```

to the product file
3. On this step application still cannot be compiled, because **org.apache.felix.scr** cannot be found. I've used approach from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025599/how-to-find-out-which-feature-contains-a-needed-plug-in-on-an-eclipse-download-s) to find in which feature **org.apache.felix.scr** is belonged - it's ***org.eclipse.e4.rcp***

4. So, I've returned to "Contents" tab and added **org.eclipse.e4.rcp** as a feature
5. After that I've pressed "Add required" and eclipse added additional features. Thus full product configuration file looks like

```
...
<launcherArgs>
      <programArgs>-consoleLog
      </programArgs>
      <vmArgs>-Xshare:auto -Declipse.ignoreApp=true -Dosgi.noShutdown=true -Dlogback.configurationFile=log.xml
      </vmArgs>
      <vmArgsLin>
         <argsX86_64>-Xmx2048m -Xms512m -XX:+UseParallelGC</argsX86_64>
      </vmArgsLin>
      <vmArgsMac>-XstartOnFirstThread -Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
      </vmArgsMac>
      <vmArgsWin>-Xmx768m -Xms256m
      </vmArgsWin>
   </launcherArgs>
...
<features>
     ... list of my features ...
      <feature id="org.eclipse.e4.rcp" installMode="root"/>
      <feature id="org.eclipse.emf.ecore" installMode="root"/>
      <feature id="org.eclipse.emf.common" installMode="root"/>
   </features>

   <configurations>
      <plugin id="org.apache.felix.scr" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.runtime" autoStart="true" startLevel="0" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.common" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.event" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator" autoStart="true" startLevel="1" />
   </configurations>
...
```